# Handle physical units in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I tend to use LibreOffice Calc most for keeping track of some sort of (measurement) data (e.g. from performed experiments). In almost all cases this data will be numbers expressing a quantity in a specific measurement unit (e.g. Joules for energy, centimeter for lengths, etc.).

What I currently do is write the unit down as part of the column header (e.g. `Measurement XY / Joules`) and then write the measured quantities as numeric values as entries in that column.

That kinda works, but has many drawbacks, e.g.:

- When performing calculations with the obtained data, the associated units are completely ignored (obviously) and thus no reasonability check can be performed (à la `eh, you're trying to add time to distance over here`)
- Converting your data from one unit into another (e.g. from centimeters to meters) usually requires a separate column next to the original one and a formula to perform the conversion for you. Thus, in effect you are duplicating your data, which harms the readability of the sheet.
- If the column header is currently not in sight (e.g. because one has scrolled too far down), the units of the data in front of you is also not imminent.

So my basic question is: What's the best (a reasonable) way of managing data with physical units in LibreOffice Calc?

---

I am aware of the `CONVERT` function that can do unit conversions, but it seems to be limited to handle only a hardcoded set of units. As far as I could find out, there is no way to extend the supported units by providing conversion factors to units natively known by the function.

If such extensions were possible, I could imagine trying to hack something together where the column header consists of two cells, where the first is the name and the second a unit dropdown menu where changing the selected unit there will auto-convert the data in the column accordingly.

---

EDIT: This question is mainly intended as a somewhat general one. The particular issues I provided were mainly given to illustrate the overall problem arising from not having native support for units.

What I am interested in, is how other people work around the different issues encountered due to this.

The particular issue that I encountered which made me dive into this whole thing was that I have a column such as

```
My Energy / Hartree
1
2
3
```

but now I am asked to give the energy in electron volts instead of Hartree. What I would like to do would be to simply change the unit in the header and then have the numeric values in the column to auto-convert accordingly.
Note that I explicitly want to avoid adding a second column that contains the same data but in eV as I think this completely clutters the spreadsheet and makes it unreadable.

Comment: Please edit the question to give a specific example and the desired result (a simplified example would probably be better than actual detailed data). From what I understand of the question so far, you could write a user-defined function to parse a number and a unit from the same cell and then convert the units, or use it with an operation from another cell or something — the question seems vague on what exactly you want. Or it doesn't have to be a UDF — you could write a spreadsheet function that parses out the units and then uses a switch statement to determine the conversion factor.

Comment: @JimK I have edited the question. But actually, the question is intended to a bit broad-ish

Comment: I'm still not seeing a specific example to work with, and that's probably why I don't understand what you mean about switching and auto-converting units. Anyway, hopefully you find my answer acceptable.

Comment: Why don't you see a specific example? I stated what I am looking for in order to convert a column of numbers from one unit to another one. Anyway, your answer _does_ definitely help me out already. It demonstrates _a_ way to cope with the issue, so that meets what I'm after.

Comment: What is the input? What is the desired output? My answer shows example input and output. Your example says to do a calculation automatically without using any other columns — I don't understand what you are imagining. Calculations in spreadsheets use columns. Anyway if what you describe were implemented, it seems terrible — auto-convert a bunch of numbers without being sure that they're the right units. I think it would be *much* safer to do it manually to avoid mistakes. (Sorry for all the edits — as you may have noticed, I tend to use comments more like a chat).

Comment: Manually means add another column, do the conversion in that column, then move that result back into the original column, deleting the now-empty column. And then be sure to rename the column so people can tell what is going on.

Comment: It is possible to change values based on drop-down lists. If you want to explore that possibility then I suggest you ask a question specifically about that, as that didn't seem to be what the original question was about. Again, I am uncomfortable with how general / vague this question is, as there is no possibility of answering it correctly. Really it should probably be closed. "Needs more focus:
This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." However, I am typically reluctant to close questions.

Comment: "Calculations in spreadsheets use columns" - I know. But I don't want to perform a _calculation_, I want to change how a given number is displayed, which in the background happens to involve a computation. I am aware that this is probably not possible, but you asked what I wanted and that's it. That's why I stated that the fundamental issue is that Calc does not support units natively.

Comment: Re: question is too broad: This question is intended as a collection rather than as a single-answer to fix specific problem. I know that these kinds of questions exist across SE, though I might have missed how to mark a question as such.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with a user-defined function. Start by entering the following in cells A1 to C3.

```
distance 1  distance 2  distance sum (cm)
~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 m         50 cm
5 m         1 m
```

Now, add this Basic code in the *Standard* library by going to *Tools > Macros > Organize Macros > Basic*.

```
Function Convert_To(sNumWithUnits As String, sDestUnit)
   aNumWithUnits = Split(sNumWithUnits)
   dNum = CDbl(aNumWithUnits(0))
   sInputUnit = aNumWithUnits(1)
   If sInputUnit = sDestUnit Then
       Convert_To = dNum
       Exit Function
   End If
   If sInputUnit = "m" and sDestUnit = "cm" Then
       conversionFactor = 100
   End If
   Convert_To = dNum * conversionFactor
End Function
```

Finally, in cell C2, enter `=(CONVERT_TO(A2;"cm")+CONVERT_TO(B2;"cm")) & " cm"` and fill down.

Result:

```
distance sum (cm)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
250 cm
600 cm
```